# In Laravel controller file, I would like to change the date format of regDate from 'Y-m-d' to 'd/m/Y'. RegDate from table is in YYYY-mm-dd

Tags: php, laravel, date, controller, format

I would like to format "regDate" to 'dd/mm/YYYY' from 'YYYY/mm/dd'. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
if ($request->keyword != "") {
  $students = Student::where
  ("name","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("nric","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("address","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("telNo","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("email","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("regDate","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->keyword) === true) {
   $request->keyword = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->keyword)->format('Y-m-d')
}

if ($request->keyword != "") {
  $students = Student::where
  ("name","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("nric","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("address","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("telNo","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("email","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orwhereDate("regDate","=","$request->keyword")
  ->get();
}
```

Check value if date you can convert to your format and then you can send query

Comment: It is working now. It was not working at first and, under trial and error, I replaced '=== true' with '== true' and it finally worked. Not sure why because I believed the '===true' should be the correct way. So, if anyone knows why it would be useful because I don't want this to come back and cause errors later. In the meantime, I will just stick with this first. Thanks for your help. Cheers

Comment: Is it true is string or boolean ?

Comment: Sorry, i haven't check that. Let me get back to you.

Comment: What do you mean? The $request->keyword is string. Then it goes to :
 
    if (DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',   $request->keyword)=== true)

Answer (score 0):

Please set your date format like below and check again.

date('d/m/Y', strtotime($request->keyword));

```
if ($request->keyword != "") {
  $students = Student::where
  ("name","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("nric","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("address","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("telNo","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("email","LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")
  ->orWhere("regDate","LIKE","%" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($request->keyword)) . "%")
  ->get();
}
```

Comment: Yes I believed that is the code to use but I would like to convert 'regDate' instead of the $request->keyword.  I tried to do it this way but it is not working.

->orWhere(date('d/m/Y', strtotime("regDate")),"LIKE","%" . $request->keyword . "%")

Comment: why you can try like this:-
->orWhere("regDate","LIKE","%" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->keyword)) . "%")

Comment: Yes tried that but still not working. Will keep on working on it. Cheers

Comment: can you share your table regDate field format or database table screenshoot

Comment: Sorry but how could I send an image?